# Probability of choosing two real numbers $a$ and $b$ from $[1,4]$ such that $ ab>4$.

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that when you pick two real numbers from the closed interval $[1,4]$, their product is greater than 4?

I tried to solve it with integration but I couldn't get the right answer. And I think that this problem can be solved without integration.

Comment: Are we choosing them from $[1,4]$ according to a uniform distribution?

Comment: And are the picks independent?

Comment: Yes, uniform and independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the figure below, I have plotted the curve $x * y = 4$, as well as the square $[1, 4] \times [1, 4]$.

[plot http://puu.sh/mtgbV/cce4527223.png](http://puu.sh/mtgbV/cce4527223.png)

Any point above the red curve and within the square has coordinates with product $> 4$. Any point on or below the red curve and within the square has coordinates with product $<= 4$. Thus the probability you are looking for is the partition of the square above the red curve, over the total area of the square.

Comment: I tried to calculate the area by integrating y=4/x from 1 to 4 and then subtracting that area from the whole square's area and then to calculate the partition of the square above the curve over the whole square, but I didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: I got it now. I was dumb and forgot that the bottom of the square wasn't on the x-axis :D

Comment: @user265554 So you knew how to do the problem. I tell my students when they make this kind of mistake that they got the mathematics right but the arithmetic wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing independence, this yields:

$P(XY\le4)=\int_1^4\int_1^{4/x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx=\int_1^4\int_1^{4/x}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}dydx=\frac{8\log 2}{9}-\frac{1}{3}$.

Then, $P(XY>4)=1-P(XY\le 4)=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{8\log 2}{9}\sim 0.717$

Comment: $f_{X,Y}$ should be $\frac{1}{9}$, no?

Comment: Yes. I confused with $F_{X,Y}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Draw the picture of $xy=4$ in the square with corners $(1,1)$ and $(4,4)$.

Comment: Is there a differencw between xy=4 and y=4/x? I tried to calculate the area under the curve y=4/x from 1 to 4, and then to subtract it from the square with area 16 to get the area of the points which are above the curve y=4/x, and then to calculate the probability but I couldn't get the right answer.